# Get data for ArcPad validation error on unfulfilled relationships

Tags: arcpad

[image]I have a file GDB with a handful of feature classes that have related tables that I am trying to check out to an AXF. I can check out an empty database just fine, no errors reported upon validation. However, when I add some sample data so that I can begin field testing, for every unfulfilled relationship (so any 1:0 relationships) I get a validation error. It's as if ArcMap is treating the relationship as a mandatory relationship.

Some additional information: I'm running ArcMap and ArcPad 10.2. All relationships are  1:M type and I've allowed Null values for each field involved in the relationship.

Anyone have any insight as to why this is happening? Are relationships mandatory?

UPDATE: I've narrowed my error issue down to this type of relationship (see attached) I'm trying to create relationship rules depending on a subtype in a table. So similar to the riverside data's poles and lights examples except for when the subtype is filament or tube I want it relate to poles using Polie_ID_PK and Pole_ID_FK and then when the subtype is "energy saver" I want the relationship to be based on Pole_ID2_PK and Pole_ID_FK.  This is the type of relationship that keeps throwing the validation error. I don’t seem to run into the same trouble if it is the origin class that has the subtypes. Does anyone know why or how this type of relationship class is not valid?